# Debian 11: make default gateway persistent and clean useless addresses

Tags: debian

I created 2 VM under VMware Player:
A: client browser 10.0.60.2
B: router 10.0.60.1 & 192.168.1.x (dhcp)
E: web router (ISP box) 192.168.1.1

https://debian-facile.org/images/file-R4a2ffa442e04c35cfda2a3f96a3f1737

I create A using the same network segment as B
so no access to the web during Debian install (no NAT, no bridge).
Just after reboot:

```
root@secbrowser:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:e7:6c:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    inet 10.0.60.2/24 brd 10.0.60.255 scope global ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.36.243/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fee7:6c32/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I don't understand what is this address :  169.254.36.243

How could I get rid of it permanently ?

My /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug ens33
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
        address 10.0.60.2/24
        gateway 10.0.60.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Impossible to reach internet:

```
oot@secbrowser:~# wget a.io
--2023-02-18 21:20:13--  http://a.io/
Résolution de a.io (a.io)… échec : Échec temporaire dans la résolution du nom.
wget : impossible to resolve host address « a.io »
```

although the 2nd rule should be enough ?

```
root@secbrowser:~# ip route show
default dev ens33 scope link 
default via 10.0.60.1 dev ens33 onlink 
10.0.60.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.60.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.36.243
```

I must type :

```
root@secbrowser:~# route add default gw 10.0.60.1
```

Now I can reach internet :

```
root@secbrowser:~# wget a.io
--2023-02-18 21:21:36--  http://a.io/
Résolution de a.io (a.io)… 85.10.133.119
Connexion à a.io (a.io)|85.10.133.119|:80… connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 301 Moved Permanently
Emplacement : https://www.a.io [suivant]
--2023-02-18 21:21:36--  https://www.a.io/
Résolution de www.a.io (www.a.io)… 85.10.133.119
Connexion à www.a.io (www.a.io)|85.10.133.119|:443… connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 200 OK
Taille : non indiqué [text/html]
Sauvegarde en : « index.html.3 »

index.html.3                      [ <=>                                           ] 156,02K  --.-KB/s    ds 0,06s   

2023-02-18 21:21:37 (2,70 MB/s) - « index.html.3 » sauvegardé [159766]
```

I can see the new rule, it the same as the 3rd one but without "onlink" (what is this?)

```
root@secbrowser:~# ip route show
default via 10.0.60.1 dev ens33 
default dev ens33 scope link 
default via 10.0.60.1 dev ens33 onlink 
10.0.60.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.60.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.36.243
```

I don't manage to make the 1st route persistent.
I tried many many things in "interfaces" file using ip command but nothing works. :(

Examples:

```
  #post-up /usr/sbin/ip route add default gw 10.0.60.1

  # ping box OK
  post-up /usr/sbin/ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.60.1
 
  #up /usr/sbin/ip route add default 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.60.1

  #up /bin/ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.60.1 dev ens33
  #up /bin/ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.60.1 dev ens33
  #up /bin/ip route add 192.168.1.1/32 via 10.0.60.1
```

Could you help me, please ?

I can post more info if needed.

Regards,

Steve.

Comment: Hi!
 Could it explain I've to type "route add default gw 10.0.60.1" to reach the web and I've troubles to make it persistent ?
No solution before having solved the unwanted ip address problem ?

Comment: Any idea to make route to default gateway persistent ???
I tried so many things in "interfaces" file....

Comment: 169.254.36.243 is a link local address often received when DHCP or other automated mechanism don't work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

Comment: Where does comme that "altname enp2s1" from ?

Comment: Any idea to make route to default gateway persistent ??? I tried so many things in "interfaces" file....

Comment: Is NetworkManager installed ?

Comment: Is wicd installed ? 

Can you add `iface enp2s1 inet manual` to your `/etc/network/interfaces` (guess directory is empty) ?

Comment: # systemctl status NetworkManager
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.


# apt list --installed | grep -i wicd
=> nothing

Comment: # apt list --installed | grep -i dhcp

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

isc-dhcp-client/stable,stable-security,now 4.4.1-2.3+deb11u1 amd64  [installé]
isc-dhcp-common/stable,stable-security,now 4.4.1-2.3+deb11u1 amd64  [installé]

root@secbrowser:~# ps -ef | grep -i dhcp
root        2915     951  0 19:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i dhcp

I don't need DHCP in this subnet, should I uninstall it ?
I  could get rid of 169.254.36.243 ?
Actually don't know what is enp2s1 ...

Comment: Why carriage returns don't work ???
It's terrible !

Comment: You'd better edit your question than respond in comments. Just comment you changed your question.

Comment: Can you search for any instance of enp2s1 in /etc ? `grep -r --col enp2s1 /etc` ? Maybe something in `/etc/network`, or `/etc/systemd/network`. `ens33` has an alternate name `enp2s1` that fail to receive addresses. It result an IPv4 and an IPv6 link local address are given to it. It should be cleaned.